# how to derive an $O(\log(n))$ expression for a sequence with $3$ terms

Tags: sequences-and-series

In my project I have to find the value of a sequence $a_n$ for a very large $n$. Let's say $n=2^{512}$.

The recurrence relation for $a_n$ is as the equation bellow:

$$a_n=12a_{n-1}-384a_{n-2}+4096a_{n-3}$$

After a quick implementation in python I found out that it is impractical to loop over this for such a large $n$.

On the other hand I see that for Fibonacci sequence there is $O(\log(n))$ solutions that express the terms based on $a_{2n}$. Is that possible to reform my sequence so that I can calculate $a_{2n}$ directly from terms $a_{n-1}, a_{n-2}, a_{n-3}$?

What if the coefficients are considered as general real numbers to form:

$$a_n=\alpha a_{n-1}+\beta a_{n-2}+\gamma a_{n-3}$$

Do you know of any alternative method to calculate $a_n$ for very large $n$ using a computer program?

Does the solution depend on initial values of the sequence $a_0, a_1, a_2$? If so they are considered to be $a_0=3, a_1=12, a_2=-624$.

Comment: Before you being calculating for $n=2^{512}$, do you have enough RAM to store the sequence value $a_n$?

Comment: I have no idea how big would be the value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A nice way to find formulae for sequences like these are with matrices. We can write

$$a_n=12a_{n−1}−384a_{n−2}+4096a_{n−3}$$
as
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
    a_{n} \\
    a_{n-1} \\
    a_{n-2} \\
\end{bmatrix}
= 
\begin{bmatrix}
    12 & -384 & 4096 \\
    1 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 1 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
    a_{n-1} \\
    a_{n-2} \\
    a_{n-3} \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

or

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
    a_{n+2} \\
    a_{n+1} \\
    a_{n} \\
\end{bmatrix}
= 
\begin{bmatrix}
    12 & -384 & 4096 \\
    1 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 1 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}^n
\begin{bmatrix}
    a_{2} \\
    a_{1} \\
    a_{0} \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Matrix exponentiation can be done quickly on a computer by diagonalizing the matrix, as then you just have to exponentiate a diagonal matrix. You can also use this to get an explicit formula of $a_n$.

To get the explicit formula you can look at the diagonalization of the matrix. $M = PDP^{-1}$ where the diagonal of D is the eigenvalues and the columns of P the corresponding eigenvectors of M. Plugging into numpy I get the approximate values of

$$
P
=
\begin{bmatrix}
    0.99865811 & 0.99865811 & 0.99584852 \\
    0.00135862-0.05170075i & 0.00135862+0.05170075i & 0.09065119 \\
    -0.00267471-0.00014067i & -0.00267471+0.00014067i & 0.0082519
\end{bmatrix}
$$
and

$$
D
=
\begin{bmatrix}
    0.50725095+19.30279482i & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0.50725095-19.30279482i & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 10.98549811
\end{bmatrix}
$$

although you could solve for the eigenvalues and eigenvectors analytically to get exact values for P and D.

You can then invert P (also can be done exactly) at which point you have

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
    a_{n+2} \\
    a_{n+1} \\
    a_{n} \\
\end{bmatrix}
= PD^nP^{-1}
\begin{bmatrix}
    a_{2} \\
    a_{1} \\
    a_{0} \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Multiplying out the matrices will then give you a vector with exact equations for $a_{n+2}$, $a_{n+1}$, and $a_{n}$. If you do this on a computer you will have round off error which means the solutions will not be exact for large n, but will give you a good approximation. If you want an exact solution you can do all the above math analytically (it will be pretty messy but not impossible) and that will give you exact formulas. Hope that makes sense!

Comment: Thank you for your response, Would you please explain more on how to get the explicit formulae?

Comment: Sure! I'll add that to my response, give me a minute.

Comment: I assume I can also replace $n$ by $2n$ and get the $O(log(n))$ solution. Right?

Comment: If you solve for the exact solution then it will technically be a O(1) solution, as you will have an equation that you just have to plug n into and it will give the answer. That being said, unless there is some crazy cancelation between terms (which there could be if this was a problem given to you by someone, if you came up with the sequence I doubt it) even calculating the 2^512th term from a formula will probably be computationally infeasible.